# List of variables in an EJS template

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm using **espress.js** and the **ejs** template engine.

I'm trying to get a list of variables sent to the view...

Here a kind of controller :

```
    homeAction(req, res) {
            res.render('index', {form: this.renderForm('aForm'), title: "My Super Title" });
    }
```

In this function, I send two variables, `form` and `title`.

Is there a way to access in my `view.ejs` to a kind of context where all variables sent to the view are listed ?

Comment: There is no built in way to get all variables passed in unless you pass all of your variables inside a single object. Then you can iterate through the object and see all of them. `res.render('index', {vars: {form: this.renderForm('aForm'), title: "My Super Title" }});` Then you can see everything in the `vars` variable in the EJS page code.

Comment: No idea why this was voted down. It's a valid question imho.

Comment: it's too bad this doesn't work, since it would have been great for recursive templates

Answer (score 2):

As @Intervalia says, you should be using a super-object which contains all your variables. But if you absolutely cannot do that, you can try using the internal variable `locals` which has all your variables (in your template, you can use `locals.form` etc). Note that this is internal to EJS, and might change/be removed with future releases of EJS so depending on this for production code is a bad idea.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore as one would expect